# OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am building a c# app that scrapes a website. I think this problem is caused because the page is reloaded after submitting the form again and again. I have to select an option from a select list then press enter and wait for the page to reload with the new results. But after reload this results in this error;

```
Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException' in WebDriver.dll
An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

My code looks like this;

```
SelectElement departmentSelect = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("select")));
IList<IWebElement> departmentOptions = departmentSelect.Options;
foreach (IWebElement option in departmentOptions)
{
    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("select"))).SelectByText(option.Text);
    driver.FindElementById("butSearchByType").Click();
}
```

I have also tried something like;

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("select"))).SelectByText(option.Text);
driver.FindElementById("butSearchByType").Click();
var ready = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("select")));
```

This just runs out of time and I get an exception of time has out.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with situation when you want do something on page but page isn't fully loaded.
In my project before any action I'm waiting for page fully loaded, and also for ajax.

it is a sample code:

```
Wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.WebDriver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```

Where Wait is a WebDriverWait.

For ajax is similar:

```
ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0")
```